# FIJI / ImageJ: How to use class from one plugin in another plugin?

Tags: plugins, imagej, fiji

I want to use the `Auto_Threshold` class - which implements the "Auto Threshold" plugin in *ImageJ*. According to http://imagej.net/Writing_plugins#The_Context, I can get access to other plugin functionality like `LogService` using

```
@Parameter
private LogService logService;
```

However, this doesn't work for everything. I tried

```
@Parameter
private Auto_Threshold AutoThreshold
```

but that doesn't work. I see from the source code at https://github.com/fiji/Auto_Threshold/blob/Auto_Threshold-1.16.5/src/main/java/fiji/threshold/Auto_Threshold.java that that class lives in the `fiji.threshold` package. Of course, I could just copy that code into my source directory and use that package. Is that the best course of action, or is there a more formal way to depend on another plugin?

Thanks,
Rory

Comment: `Auto_Threshold` is an ImageJ 1.x style plugin, and `@Parameter`s are a SciJava feature and therefore part of ImageJ2. Have a look at the forum discussions about parameters: https://forum.image.sc/tags/parameters It should be as simple as `import fiji.threshold.Auto_Threshold`, and defining the dependency in your `pom.xml`, but please ask on https://forum.image.sc with some more description of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommandService maybe:

```
@Parameter
private CommandService cs;
```

Then whenever you want to do something:

```
cs.run(OtherPlugin.class, true, ...)
```